# Some files in system32 not visible/accessible for Java program

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, exe

I'm trying to write a Java application that is supposed to call an exe file with some arguments and process the output. I tried Runtime.getRuntime().exec() in several variations and also the ProcessBuilder class, nothing worked - it said it couldn't find the file, despite the path environment variable being correct.

Out of ideas, I tried the following:

```
File f = new File("C:\\Windows\\system32\\query.exe");
System.out.println(f.exists());
```

It said `false`.

I thought, maybe there's something wrong with the path (the backslashes? capitalization?) and tried the following:

```
FileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("C:\\Windows\\System32");
chooser.setFileHidingEnabled(false);
chooser.showOpenDialog(null);       
File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
System.out.println(f.exists());
```

The file is **not** displayed in the FileChooser (if I manually enter it in the FileChooser, the result is `false` again). But I've double-checked, it **is** there. I've got the Explorer window opened right now. I can start it from within cmd.exe. `where query` prints `C:\\Windows\\System32\\query.exe`.

I thought it could be related to access rights, but I've compared the security settings of the query file with others which are visible; they're the same. I ran Eclipse as Administrator, same result. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that the JVM is executing as a 32-bit process and the OS is 64-bit, meaning [File System Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is occurring:

> In most cases, whenever a 32-bit application attempts to access `%windir%\System32`, the access is redirected to `%windir%\SysWOW64`.

If you check under `C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64` the `query.exe` does not exist, explaining the behaviour you are witnessing.

Comment: Indeed, there's no query.exe in there. Wow, never heard about this behaviour. Thank you so much.